# jQuery to change element Attributes and return the edited Html Source back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Actually what i'm doing is to find the `<img>` image tags and get its `src` attribute to change them.

I already got upto this point but the problem more is: To get the `edited` the html source back (to put into the database.)

To say more brief & clearly, i'm about to grab some `Dynamic Html Containers` and then change the image paths and save the whole source chunk back.

For brief example if i search inside `$(div.container).html()` on this:

```
<div class="container">
    <..> .. </..>
    <..>
        <img src="images/apple.jpg" />
        <..>
            <img src="images/banana.jpg" />
        </..>
    </..>
</div>
```

- Firstly, lets say `<..>` represent any of not previously knowable html tags.

Then i will get:

```
var dom_contents = $("div.container").html();
```

- Now i got the original `html source` inside the target container `<div>`
- Then lets say i need to change each `<img src` with `sample/` for its folder. It will then be `fruits/apple.jpg` and `fruits/banana.jpg`.. etc.

I still getting some of the stuffs like:

```
$("div.container).each(function() {
    var arr = $(this).find("img");
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var img_src = $(arr[i]).attr("src");
        /*
         * I NEED TO CHANGE THE IMAGE SRC HERE
         */
    }
});
```

- ** Finally, i need to save this **the whole edited html source** into the database. **

  - So how do i change the `<img src=''` .. and
  - How do i get this `whole edited html source`, back from the jQuery?

Comment: `$('someSelector').html()` gives you a HTML representation of the selected elements.

Comment: But that is only the `original` source. NOT THE ONE AFTER EDITED.

Comment: Uhm, no, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ApE63/

Comment: @4lvin `.html()` returns the live html. If you apply changes to the original dom-nodes, `html()` is also affected.

Answer (score 2):

Amend the source attribute for each image as follows. You don't need to write the html back. The source html will be updated:

```
$("div.container").each(function() {
    $(this).find("img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/image/url/file.png");
    });
});
```

To get the html source of the container, use the following:

```
$("div.container").html();
```

Comment: Woah its simple & best, mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will set the attribute:

```
$(arr[i]).attr("src", mynewsrcvalue);
```

Once you're done just send the `innerHTML` (or `.html()`) back in an AJAX request.  But if you want this stuff in a database, why not just manipulate the source on the server side in the first place?